# Convergence of backpropagation algorithm : how many iterations?

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm new to the world of neural network, which is very interesting. I wrote the basic algorithm of backpropagation on multi-layer NN to solve small problems.
I use the activation function sigmoid (like most of you I think) (x->1/(1+exp(-x))).
I tried my program on several problems :

- The first one is the XOR problem. I took a 3 layers network of size [2,2,1] with one bias neuron in the two first layers (so actually the size is more [3,3,1]).
  It tried it with 1000 sets of data (i.e. a couple (0/1, 0/1) and its XOR as output), and the algorithm seemed to converge at an error of 0.5 :( I found it weird so i raised the number to 10000, and as it didn't change anything, to 100000 (in despair :p) and it WORKS ! The error fell down to less that 0.02 in average. Does anybody have an idea why it needs so much data to work?
- The second one is the sum problem between two numbers (like 4+8 = ?). I took randomly a [2, 5, 5, 1] network with one bias neuron in the three first layers (so actually the size is more [3, 6, 6, 1]). I put a training data set of 100000 couples of numbers below 100 and their sum. This time, the error does not converge at all, while the output of the network always return the number 1. Have you already seen such situations ? Is it a bug code ? (code that i checked many times but perhaps).

```
import random
import math
```

class Network:
    def initdata(self):
        #weights initialization
        self.weights.append([])
        self.threshold.append([])
        for l in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            n = self.layers[l]
            thresholdl = []
            weightsl = []
            for i in range(n):
                thresholdl.append(-random.random())
                weightsli = []
                for j in range(self.layers[l-1]):
                    weightsli.append(random.random()*2-1)
                #adding bias neurons
                weightsli.append(thresholdl[-1])
                weightsl.append(weightsli)
            self.weights.append(weightsl)
            self.threshold.append(thresholdl)

    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers
        self.weights = []
        self.threshold = []
        self.initdata()

    def activation_function(self, x):
        return 1/(1+math.exp(-x))

    def outputlayer(self, input, l):
        if l==0:
            return [input]
        output = []
        prevoutput = self.outputlayer(input, l-1)
        for i in range(self.layers[l]):
            f = 0
            for k in range(len(prevoutput[-1])):
                f += self.weights[l][i][k]*prevoutput[-1][k]
            f += self.weights[l][i][-1] #bias weight !
            output.append(self.activation_function(f))
        return prevoutput+[output]

    def layersoutput(self, input):
        return self.outputlayer(input, len(self.layers)-1)

    def finaloutput(self, input):
        return self.layersoutput(input)[-1]

    def train(self, data, nu):
        for (input, finaloutput) in data:
            output = self.layersoutput(input)
            err = self.errorvector(finaloutput, output[-1])
            self.changeweights(err, output, nu)

    def changeweights(self, err, output, nu):
        deltas = []
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            deltas.append([])
        tempweights = self.weights.copy()
        def changeweightslayer(layer):
            if layer != len(self.layers)-1:
                changeweightslayer(layer+1)
            for i in range(self.layers[layer]):
                delta = 0
                if layer != len(self.layers)-1:
                    delta = output[layer][i]*(1-output[layer][i])*sum([deltas[layer+1][l]*self.weights[layer+1][l][i] for l in range(self.layers[layer+1])])
                else:
                    delta = output[layer][i]*(1-output[layer][i])*err[i]
                deltas[layer].append(delta)
                for k in range(len(self.weights[layer][i])-1):
                    tempweights[layer][i][k] += nu*output[layer-1][k]*delta
                tempweights[layer][i][-1] += nu*delta
        changeweightslayer(1)
        self.weights = tempweights


    def quadraticerror(self, a, b):
        return sum([(a[i]-b[i])**2 for i in range(len(a))])

    def errorvector(self, a, b):
        return [a[i]-b[i] for i in range(len(a))]

network = Network([2, 5, 5, 1])
print(network.weights)
data = []
for i in range(1000000):
    bit1 = random.randrange(100)
    bit2 = random.randrange(100)
    data.append(([float(bit1), float(bit2)], [float(bit1+bit2)]))
network.train(data, 0.1)
print(network.weights)

Comment: 1) It would be good if you posted your code and 2) maybe this should be posted on code review?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Added. Thanks guys i'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: On the sum problem it is likely because you apply the activation function, 1/(1+math.exp(-x)), to the output? It can not go above 1.0, so it would be better to have a linear activation function on the output.

Comment: Yes i didn't noticed it. Actually the sum problem seems not adapted to this kind of neural network, even when changing the activation function. If somebody knows more on this problem ? (type of neural network adapted ?)